# Need to read USB CDC data (UART over USB) from instrument using STM32F103C8T6 Blue Pill

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc

I have our old instrument which are showing flow over USB port using (Communication Device Class ASF Example). I am able to get data over UART 115200 using Teraterm.

I want to have this data parsed into MCU. It is possible to use STM32F103C8T6 Blue Pill for this application? Or do I need Raspberry PI type PC?

I am very new to USB interfaced so please guide for the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your "old instrument" acts as a *USB device*. In order to communicate with it, a *USB host* is needed. The Blue Pill is restricted to USB device. So it cannot communicate with another USB device. You will need a microcontroller or computer with USB host support.

Comment: Any USB Host IC that i would use with existing microcontroller?

Comment: There is no need for a separate IC. USB host is integrated in many microcontrollers, e.g. STM32F4 family. The main challenge is the software, not the hardware. Make sure you are using a framework that support USB CDC as host.

Comment: ok thanks for your guidance.